# FromForm annotation not supported in MapPost()ed methods?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, webapi, .net-6.0

.NET 6, purely WebAPI project. I have an endpoint method that is expecting a urlencoded form in the POST data. The method is added to the routing table by `app.MapPost("/myendpoint", MyClass.MyEndpoint)` in the program's startup file; it's not in a controller. The method currently goes:

```
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
[HttpPost]
public static async Task<IResult> MyEndpoint([FromForm]FormData TheForm)
```

where `FormData` is a record with the expected form fields.

I've tried some other annotations. The framework just won't let me consume the form. When invoked, the method either returns HTTP error 415, or, in some iterations, an exception is thrown somewhere in the pipeline saying that "Expected a supported JSON media type but got "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"."

Is urlencoded form parameter binding even supported in WebAPI? I would even settle for the form contents as a string, won't mind parsing myself (`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to the rescue).

For the time being, I read `Request.Body` from the HTTP context' request body, but that's crude and also error prone, as the context is known to go poof sometimes in async methods.

EDIT: also tried placing `.Accepts<FormData>("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` on the MapPost() line. Same result.

Tried replacing the body parameter with `[FromBody]byte [] Body`, `[FromBody]string Body`.

Comment: You don' t need any annotations at all, remove all of them. It is about the way you are trying to post data. If you want to get some help you need to show your code that you use to submit the form.

Comment: The form is being submitted by a third party site, not by my code. I can see it's a valid POST with valid urlencoded data.

Comment: Then it is not your problem. Tell them to fix their code or post the code here in order we could help them.

Comment: The fact that they are sending a urlencoded form (as opposed to a JSON) to a callback endpoint of mine is a part of their spec that I have to conform to.

Comment: You can test your Api using a Postman. It it works, everything is fine

Comment: I am testing it using a generic HTTP client. It doesn't work. I am unable to tell the framework that this particular endpoint expects its inputs in a form, not in a JSON. The [FromForm] annotation on the method parameter doesn't work. The errors the framework is throwing all mean "we expect a JSON".